# After changing from DLL to nuget http-methods don't work in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, model-view-controller, http2

I had a DBConnector subproject linked to the main project using a DLL. Later DBConnector migrated to Nuget. After migration no one http-method called by ajax-functions works. The error in browser says "browserLink:1     Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR".
What could be the problem?

I supposed the problem could be in browser. After browser updating problem still exists. Also developer of DBConnector changed version of Microsoft.Extensions.Http from 7 to 6. Still no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem consisted in TempData that I saved between get-queries. As the Model resets after every get-query (that was not the case of ajax-methods), I was need to save it. I rebuilt the way of collecting data as ajax-functions without view update and removed TempData. Now Http works.